# What is the name for this "..." punctuation?

Tags: punctuation, names

When I am writing, and I want to leave something out, so that it gives an implied effect, I use this: *...*

What is it called?

Comment: Simply typing a punctuation mark into the search box on Wikipedia gets you right to the corresponding article.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> **[ellipsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis)** noun (plural *ellipses*)
>   the omission from speech or writing of a word or words that are superfluous or able to be understood from contextual clues.
>   • ***a set of dots indicating such an omission***.

<sup>(*New Oxford American Dictionary*)</sup>

It is represented in Unicode by the glyph U+2026 HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS: **…**

The details of typesetting ellipses is discussed briefly in the Wikipedia article linked above. In short, the decision is on how much space you put between the individual dots. This is a styling issue, which is settled by each publisher. (For example, in French, it is typical not to space them out more than three normal dots.)

Comment: FWIW, on the (standard) Mac keyboard, you can generate an … with [alt]+";".

Comment: On Windows, you can type … with Alt+Num 0133 (i.e. hold down the [left] Alt key, type 0133 on the numeric keypad, then release the Alt key).

Comment: Technically, they are called "points of ellipsis," and come in the 3- and 4-dot string. In professional typesetting, manuscript is prepared with manual periods - never the ellipsis character available in some typefaces - so that the typesetter can customize the space between the periods as required.

Comment: On European keyboard layouts, the shortcut is alt+x.

Comment: @KristianAntonsen: that may be true for certain layouts, but it is definitely not the norm for European keyboards. Also, shortcuts are dependent on the OS and can be customized by the user.

Comment: @nico: My comment was a bit vague. What I meant to say is that on standard Mac European keyboards, it's alt+x.

Comment: @KristianAntonsen: Ok, Mac is probably different as the keyboards are standardised for the OS!

Comment: Right here on ELU as in other Web docs, the html code is **&hellip;** -- you can include that in the midst of text while posting questions and answers on ELU. Here it is: …

Answer (score 0):

It's called an *ellipsis* which can make things sound more dangerous than they are, or it can be used so you don't put at the end more next time.

Comment: Check your spellings and grammar before hitting that "Post Your Answer" button. Hit "edit" if you already did. :)

Comment: The edit seems to be a guess as to what the answer meant to say. @Katie: What do you really mean to say here?